# Best approach: tree set structure vs thread pool executor

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, priority-queue, threadpoolexecutor

Guys I'm in bit dilemma between `Tree Set` and `Thread Pool Executor`

Following is the scenario :

First Approach

1. I have to use structure which has tasks in it with priorities of each task.Now based on `treeset constructor`(with `comparator` interface)
2. I can compare task on priorities and based on that, tasks are ordered properly.
3. Now after that, tasks should processed in order of priority through iteration of tree set and execute each task one by one.

Second Approach

1. second approach is to do some sort of logic building and use core functionality of `Thread pool executor` and for this I had taken inspiration from [this link](http://funofprograming.blogspot.in/2013/11/priorityexecutorservice-for-java.html) and I had achieved my requirements with this approach also which will choose high priority task first and execute it first and same way it will execute all the tasks.

Now my confusion here is which one is best to use in term of performance costs, flexibility(increase/decrease threads) etc  and why should I opt for it?

Any suggestions and answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the thread pool priority is guaranteed to make those threads go first, so your tree set sounds better.

Comment: Most examples with Executors that I've seen make use of Queues.  Why not use `PriorityQueue` with the same comparator?  Asking which is "best" is really up to your use case and work load, as there's no one answer that will always work for your particular task.

Comment: @Evan knowles I had made a raw prototype of `thread pool executor` model and got expected results if you want the output you can take a look on example provided in above question's link which contains main method example and its output makes it more descriptive

Comment: @Makoto I have implement priority queue and I got expected results but M looking for best solutions in terms of performance costs and flexibility

Comment: That's really up to you to evaluate; we don't know how many runnable tasks you're going to run at any given moment, nor do we know anything about the server load or strain that would be put on the environment during a normal operation.  I'd say invest in profiler to determine the *best* way - it's really up to your use case.

Comment: You should only be concerned about performance when you actually encounter performance problems; it has been suggested that you use a `PriorityQueue`, you say you had your code work with that, so leave it to that; come back to the performance problem when it actually appears!

Comment: Is the tree set just used to decide in which order tasks should be *started*, or in which order they should be *completed*?

Comment: Secondly, in the first scenario, how are the tasks  processed ?

Comment: @didierc I am using tree set for tasks in which order is as per priority to complete given task first i.e task with higher priority should get completed first.so tree set contains order like tasks from higher priority to lower priority.

Comment: @didierc as mentioned in question they are processed by iterating tree set and taking each task getting it for further execution.

Comment: OK, à thread poll does not provide the guarantee that tasks get completed in any given order, they only start them in the order they're given. If you know that task A must be completed before task B starts, it must be enforced by a different mechanism. I suppose that your priority queue could be used for that, but it is inherently linear. A good idea for modeling that sort of dependency is a directed acyclic graph: arrows represent dependency, and a node a task. At first all arrows are marked false. Each time a task is completed, all the arrows leaving it are marked *true*

Comment: When all arrows leaving to a node are marked true, that node's task may be started. This way you can ensure proper terminatiom ordering.

Comment: The threadpool is only there to optimise resource usage.

Comment: @didierc with the help of [this link](http://funofprograming.blogspot.in/2013/11/priorityexecutorservice-for-java.html) I had achieved tasks ordering and executions.thanks for your valuable suggestion but m curious to know between `treeset` and `thread pool executor` that who is better than the other.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You mean runtime priority, which, assuming all tasks are of equal duration, would imply that higher priority tasks would be completed first.

Comment: @didierc yes that's what it exactly does but now coming to the question which is best `tree set`or `thread pool executor` and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally** got the real winner out of this two. I should select for `Thread pool Executor` because of following reasons

1. **Performance cost**: Here if we see, using  a resource maximum is main motive to get performance during heavy load.So if we use threads in this high time it will be providing high performance as an advantage of multi-threading .
2. **Flexibility**:Flexibility in terms of scalable use of resources i.e during low time we can reduce number of worker threads in `thread pool executor` architecture and vice versa.
3. **Less number of iterations and minimal updates**:If we maintain tree set every time, it will check with the help of `comparator` interface though it has complexity **O(logn)** but after that we have to fetch it and it will become a sequential flow of single source so we will not multi-threaded environment advantage.
4. **Faster processing**:With the help of threading architecture we can achieve faster output.

etc were the reasons which I pointed out during a heavy brain storming,googling and last but not the least stack Overflow searching. Thank you all for your humble support and huge appreciation to @didierc for getting me clear over it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different notions of priority embedded in your question:

- starting priority: in which order *tasks* are submitted for execution, (point 1 of your first approach explanation)
- runtime priority: in which order *threads* are considered for scheduling (point 3)

These two properties happen to be equal in your scenario, so the tree set will help you define both of them. The executor will help you enforce them, but you will need an ad-hoc tailored executor (based on thread pooling or not), to start your threads up with a specific priority. Basically, each time a task is pulled out of the priority queue, it should be associated with a thread set at the task's priority level. I assume that this is the feature that the executor implementation found in the article you link is providing, and thus what you do.

As for thread pools, from the documentation:

> Using worker threads minimizes the overhead due to thread creation. Thread objects use a significant amount of memory, and in a large-scale application, allocating and deallocating many thread objects creates a significant memory management overhead.

Worker threads are threads managed by threadpools, and are conservatively recycled (as opposed to destroyed and recreated), to handle sequences of tasks. I Don't think it matters much with regard to priority handling, but it will optimise your usage of resources.

Regarding the implementation from the article, the code uses a simple blocking deque for handling incoming tasks,  hence it's a plain fifo priority scheme. It doesn't reorder tasks.

Comment: Exactly, the feature (thread's priority is same as that of task) is implemented in second approach. `tree set` approach is good but my confusion is about the time complexity,performance costs during heavy tasks load, flexibility etc based on which one to choose.?

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that point. I guess that without specific implementation details it will be difficult to evaluate them in terms of complexity & cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DelayedQueue in ordinary threadpool.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(size, size, 0, TimeUnit.DAYS, new DelayQueue<>());
threadPoolExecutor.execute(runnable);
```

**Runnable** should be implements **Comparable** . So In this implementation , priority will taken care by delayedqueue.

This approach will be easier to implement.